# Linux driver debugging NULL pointer usage

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

Im learning to develop and backport drivers and Im new to this.
I am wondering how to debug this issue. I found that there is some usage of NULL pointer but I dont know how to find it. This debug trace doesn't shows me where it is in the driver code. And I dont know how to start.

I succeeded to backport `mcp251xfd` driver to 4.9 linux and it works, I succeeded to read data with candump but when I do reboot this happens: ( and sometimes happens on bringing up the interface)

```
 [   35.383520] Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address 000000c8
[   35.392667] pgd = ffffff80094a1000
[   35.396502] [000000c8] *pgd=000000007f7fe003, *pud=000000007f7fe003, *pmd=0000000000000000
[   35.405833] Internal error: Oops: 96000005 [#1] PREEMPT SMP
[   35.412105] Modules linked in: vin_v4l2 ov8858_r2a_4lane vin_io videobuf2_dma_contig gt9xxnew_ts sprdbt_tty sprdwl_ng uwe5622_bsp_sdio sunxi_gmac
[   35.426863] CPU: 3 PID: 0 Comm: swapper/3 Not tainted 4.9.170 #2
[   35.432909] NOHZ: local_softirq_pending 08
[   35.433034] NOHZ: local_softirq_pending 08
[   35.433125] NOHZ: local_softirq_pending 08
[   35.447419] Hardware name: sun50iw10 (DT)
[   35.451931] task: ffffffc03e1cc880 task.stack: ffffffc03e1e0000
[   35.458608] PC is at test_and_set_bit+0x18/0x40
[   35.463713] LR is at __netif_schedule+0x28/0x80
[   35.468811] pc : [<ffffff80083fddb8>] lr : [<ffffff80087e5588>] pstate: 40400145
[   35.477129] sp : ffffffc03f733d70
[   35.480856] x29: ffffffc03f733d70 x28: 000000000002536] 3cf0  3b36d4a0 ffffffc0 3b2f6c80 ffffffc0 00000003 00000000 ffffffff 00000000
[   35.591815] 3d10  0000000a 00000000 08e8f018 ffffff80 00000001 00000000 3f733d70 ffffffc0
[   35.601089] 3d30  087e5588 ffffff80 3f733d70 ffffffc0 083fddb8 ffffff80 40400145 00000000
[   35.610363] 3d50  3b36d000 ffffffc0 00000001 00000000 ffffffff 0000007f 3b36d4a0 ffffffc0
[   35.619637] 3d70  3f733da0 ffffffc0 087e5610 ffffff80 3b2f6c00 ffffffc0 00000001 00000000
[   35.628911] 3d90  3b2f6c00 ffffffc0 087e55fc ffffff80 3f733dc0 ffffffc0 088162f0 ffffff80
[   35.638185] 3db0  3b36d000 ffffffc0 00000001 00000000 3f733e10 ffffffc0 08114920 ffffff80
[   35.647459] 3dd0  00000101 00000000 3b36d4b8 ffffffc0 088161f4 ffffff80 088161f4 ffffff80
[   35.656742]
[   35.656742] X6: 0xffffffc03f733e68:
[   35.662328] 3e68  08e93000 ffffff80 0920d000 ffffff80 09206000 ffffff80 09210000 ffffff80
[   35.671603] 3e88  ffffffff 00000000 00000101 00000000 08114c1c ffffff80 3f733f30 ffffffc0
[   35.680876] 3ea8  08081438 ffffff80 09205188 ffffff80 00000001 00000000 00000002 00000000
[   35.690149] 3ec8  09412e80 ffffff80 00000282 00000000 08e8f018 ffffff80 00000000 00000000
[   35.699422] 3ee8  0841cb98 ffffff80 09205188 ffffff80 00000001 00000000 00000002 00000000
[   35.708694] 3f08  09412e80 ffffff80 00000282 00000000 08081328 ffffff80 3f733f30 ffffffc0
[   35.717968] 3f28  000409aa 00000000 3f733fc0 ffffffc0 080aa3a8 ffffff80 09412e80 ffffff80
[   35.727242] 3f48  00000005 00000000 08cf4000 ffffff80 00000000 00000000 08e98000 ffffff80
[   35.736535]
[   35.736535] X21: 0xffffffc03b2f6b80:
[   35.742218] 6b80  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   35.751490] 6ba0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   35.760762] 6bc0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   35.770034] 6be0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 0000000000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   35.831355] d440  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   35.840625] d460  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   35.849897] d480  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000064 00000000
[   35.859169] d4a0  00310030 0000012c 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   35.868441] d4c0  3f734ff0 ffffffc0 fffecaff 00000000 088161f4 ffffff80 3b36d000 ffffffc0
[   35.877714] d4e0  18000003 ffffffff 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   35.886987] d500  08ea3fdc ffffff80 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 3b36d518 ffffffc0
[   35.896264]
[   35.896264] X23: 0xffffffc03b2f6c00:
[   35.901947] 6c00  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   35.911219] 6c20  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   35.920491] 6c40  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   35.929763] 6c60  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   35.939038] 6c80  00010001 ffffffff 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   35.948310] 6ca0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   35.957583] 6cc0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   35.966856] 6ce0  00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[   35.976137]
[   35.976137] X29: 0xffffffc03f733cf0:
[   35.981821] 3cf0  3b36d4a0 ffffffc0 3b2f6c80 ffffffc0 00000003 00000000 ffffffff 00000000
[   35.991093] 3d10  0000000a 00000000 08e8f018 ffffff80 00000001 00000000 3f733d70 ffffffc0
[   36.000367] 3d30  087e5588 ffffff80 3f733d70 ffffffc0 083fddb8 ffffff80 40400145 00000000
[   36.009640] 3d50  3b36d000 ffffffc0 00000001 00000000 ffffffff 0000007f 3b36d4a0 ffffffc0
[   36.018914] 3d70  3f733da0 ffffffc0 087e5610 ffffff80 3b2f6c00 ffffffc0 00000001 00000000
[   36.028187] 3d90  3b2f6c00 ffffffc0 087e55fc ffffff80 3f733dc0 ffffffc0 088162f0 ffffff80
[   36.037464] 3db0  3b36d000 ffffffc0 00000001 00000000 3f733e10 ffffffc0 08114920 ffffff80
[   36.046737] 3dd0  00000101 00000000 3b36d4b8 ffffffc0 088161f4 ffffff80 088161f4 ffffff80
[   36.056010]
[   36.057689] Process swapper/3 (pid: 0, stack limit = 0xffffffc03e1e0000)
[   36.065231] Stack: (0xffffffc03f733d70 to 0xffffffc03e1e4000)
[   36.071694] Call trace:
[   36.074449] Exception stack(0xffffffc03f733b80 to 0xffffffc03f733cb0)
[   36.081705] 3b80: 0000000000000000 0000007fffffffff 00000000414a3000 ffffff80083fddb8
[   36.090520] 3ba0: 0000000040400145 ffffffc03e21dda0 0000000000000000 ffffffc03f73b780
[   36.099336] 3bc0: ffffffc03f733d30 0000000000000000 ffffffc03f733c00 0000000000000000
[   36.108151] 3be0: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000400
[   36.116966] 3c00: 0000000000000018 0000000100000000 0000000000000001 0000000000000000
[   36.125781] 3c20: 0000000000000000 ffffffc03e21df00 0000000000000006 00000000000409aa
[   36.134597] 3c40: 0000000000000000 00000000000000c8 0000000000000001 0000000000000000
[   36.143413] 3c60: 0000000000000001 000000000000000f ffffffc03f733ee8 0800000000000000
[   36.152227] 3c80: 0000000000000001 0000000000000000 0000000000000004 000000000000000f
[   36.161037] 3ca0: 0000000000000000 000000000000004c
[   36.166536] [<ffffff80083fddb8>] test_and_set_bit+0x18/0x40
[   36.172813] [<ffffff80087e5610>] netif_schedule_queue+0x30/0x40
[   36.179482] [<ffffff80088162f0>] dev_watchdog+0xfc/0x278
[   36.185467] [<ffffff8008114920>] call_timer_fn+0xa4/0x1c0
[   36.191546] [<ffffff8008114b8c>] expire_timers+0x124/0x170
[   36.197723] [<ffffff8008114c90>] run_timer_softirq+0xb8/0x188
[   36.204192] [<ffffff8008081438>] __do_softirq+0x178/0x338
[   36.210272] [<ffffff80080aa3a8>] irq_exit+0x90/0xd0
[   36.215767] [<ffffff80000012 0000000000000000 000000000000002d
[   36.270918] 3ea0: 000000000000001f 0000000000000000 ffffff800821c950 0000007faa340698
[   36.279734] 3ec0: 0000007faa3caa70 ffffff800920df48 0000000000000003 0000000000000008
[   36.288549] 3ee0: ffffff800920dfdc ffffffc03e1cc880 0000000000000000 0000000000000000
[   36.297363] 3f00: 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 0000000000000000 ffffffc03e1e3f60
[   36.306179] 3f20: ffffff800808577c ffffffc03e1e3f60 ffffff8008085780 0000000060400145
[   36.314995] 3f40: ffffffc03e1cc880 ffffff800810c27c ffffffffffffffff ffffff8008085700
[   36.323808] [<ffffff8008082b68>] el1_irq+0xe8/0x18c
[   36.329302] [<ffffff8008085780>] arch_cpu_idle+0x98/0x178
[   36.335385] [<ffffff80089fed18>] default_idle_call+0x28/0x30
[   36.341759] [<ffffff80080f2394>] cpu_startup_entry+0xc4/0x104
[   36.348231] [<ffffff8008091034>] secondary_start_kernel+0x1d0/0x1dc
[   36.355285] [<0000000040a011b4>] 0x40a011b4
[   36.360002] Code: d2800022 8b400c21 f9800031 9ac32044 (c85f7c22)
[   36.366860] ---[ end trace a8e12e41d725d1cb ]---
[   36.372057] Kernel panic - not syncing: Fatal exception in interrupt
[   36.379202] SMP: stopping secondary CPUs
[   36.383621] Kernel Offset: disabled
[   36.387563] Memory Limit: none
[   36.391016] Rebooting in 5 seconds..
```

Firstly I wasnt able to bring up the interface with similar problem and I readed that this is buffer overflow or double free. From the previous dump I saw in which function the problem happens and I commented this line -> `kfree(ram);` @ 1034 line @ this file --> https://github.com/minima34/mcp251xfd_4.9/blob/master/mcp251xfd/mcp251xfd-core.c

This allowed me to get my driver working but now I have this nasty issue, that blocked me and freaked me. This time I can't see where the problem happens and its confusing.

I think that the problem is that I commented `kfree()` in 1034 line but I dont know how to do it then.

Comment: Well, seems to me like you are inside `test_and_set_bit` at offset `+0x18`, which was called by `__netif_schedule` and the return should happen at `__netif_schedule+0x28`. You can inspect these functions in the C source code and in a disassembler (such as `objdump`) and figure out what caused the problem. Alternatively you can check the address of those symbols (`__netif_schedule` and `test_and_set_bit`) in the symbols of your `vmlinux` (assuming you have it compiled with debug info) and then add the offset and use `addr2line -e vmlinux 0xADDR` to check the corresponding source code file/line.

Comment: You wrote that panic happens on either initialization or reboot, but looking into commented line I believe these might be two different issues. For the line you have commented out I might give you a hint - you didn't think `regmap_raw_write` might be asynchronous?

Comment: Your problem quite likely is UAF (use-after-free) or accessing non-initialized (yet) object. Either way, it seems like a race condition due to misunderstanding of possible scheduling scenarios (IRQ, timer, etc).